# Beautifulsoup save links to list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve links from some website and save it to the list for further use.
What I got so far (it's my .txt file where I store the output):

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="/review/huerco-s-those-you-who-have-never-and-also-those-w/">Huerco S.<span><i>For Those Of You Who Have Never (And  Also Those Who Have)</i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/dam-funk-dj-kicks/">Dâm-Funk<span><i>DJ-Kicks</i>  </span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/skepta-konnichiwa/">Skepta<span><i>Konnichiwa</i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/jessy-lanza-oh-no/">Jessy Lanza<span><i>Oh No</i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/radiohead-moon-shaped-pool/">Radiohead<span><i>A Moon Shaped Pool</i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/brodka-clashes/">Brodka<span><i>Clashes</i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/james-blake-colour-anything/">James Blake<span><i> The Colour In Anything</i></span></a></li>
<li><a href="/review/kamaiyah-good-night-ghetto/">Kamaiyah<span><i>A Good Night In The Ghetto</i></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And I want to extract those specific links to the list.
My code:

```
website = "http://www.porcys.com/review/"
openWebsite = soup(urllib.request.urlopen(website), 'html.parser')
reviews = openWebsite.find(name="section", attrs={'class': 'slider-content review'}).ul
for a in reviews(href = True):
    temp = str("http://www.porcys.com"+str(a['href']))
    print(temp)
```

Print outputs exactly what I want (that means - just links, without any html tags), but I'm having difficulties with moving it to list. I tried

```
results[a] = temp
a+=1
```

but im getting "list indices must be integers or slices, not Tag"

Comment: list.append(temp) doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is happening because `a` is a `Tag`, and you're trying to access the *"**Tag**th"* element of results instead of *"**i**th"* element, where ***i*** is some integer index or slice. What you can do instead, is define the list of your results and append `temp` to it.

```
results = []
for a in reviews(href=True):
    temp = "http://www.porcys.com" + a['href']
    print(temp)
    results.append(temp)

print results
```

You can also do this in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
results = ["http://www.porcys.com"+a['href'] for a in reviews(href=True)]
print results
```

Comment: Why the str calls everywehre?

Comment: Oh, good point @PadraicCunningham updating - I had just copied the asker's command without putting much thought into it.

Comment: I think it was an attempt at fixing the error on the OPs part. `a['href']` will also return a str